# ERROR MySQL server PID file could not be found in OSX Sierra

Tags: mysql, database, macos, macos-sierra

I know that there is dozens of articles about this but none of them works for me. I've tried everything, install mysql from official site, from brew, and always have the sam problem:

`ERROR MySQL server PID file could not be found`

tried to change permissions for directories, change sources, moving and recreating `my.cnf` file, etc. nothing works. I'm powerless...

I have `oSX Sierra 10.12.2` and i've installed `mysql-5.7.17`. Maybe some of you found solution for this setup, configuration... Much thx for help and don't removing this question.

Answer (score 5):

This question is outdated but still a relevant issue, which I solved on my MacBook running macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.2).

Run the following command:

```
mysql.server status
```

Should return: ERROR! MySQL is running but PID file could not be found

To resolve the issue, find all running MySQL instances

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

This will list the processes using MySQL, listing results similar to below:

> 1768   0.0  0.0  4267768    896 s000  S+   12:08am   0:00.00 grep
>   mysql

End *ALL* the MySQL pids returned:

```
sudo kill <pid1> <pid2> <pid3> ...
```

This should kill off all the mysql processes

Now try to starting MySQL again...

```
mysql.server start
```

> Starting MySQL . SUCCESS!

Hopefully this will save someone hours of endless Googling!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data/*

sudo apachectl restart

sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

I had this issue as well. Followed some instructions from [here](https://www.flyweb.at/blog/network/1001/error-mysql-server-pid-file-could-not-be-found).